# Concatenate fields in Access

Tags: query, ms-access

How come my statement is getting marked wrong? The question is:

> Create a query based on the `tblCustomer` and `tblPurchase` tables that will concatenate the member’s first and last names (separated by a space) followed by the date they made a purchase. Name the concatenated field `Purchase Details`. Use a comma to separate the full name and date, in that order. Save your query as `qryPurchaseDetails` and then close the query.

My answer is:

```
Purchase Details: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] & "," & [PurchaseDate]
```

When I run it on Access, it works fine but the grader is marking me wrong. Any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `[PurchaseDate]` has a data type of `Date/Time` therefore it would be more correct to convert to a string before concatenating it to other strings. It might not give an error in Access, but you're taking your chances that you'll like the date format that Access chooses.

`Purchase Details: [FirstName] & " " [LastName] & "," & FormatDateTime([PurchaseDate],2)`

Or

`Purchase Details: [FirstName] & " " [LastName] & "," & Format([PurchaseDate],"yyyy-mm-dd")`

[Documentation for FormatDateTime()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FormatDateTime-Function-aef62949-f957-4ba4-94ff-ace14be4f1ca)

[Format()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)

Comment: How come you included ",2" at the end of the first line you sent?

Comment: The 2 is an optional argument of the FormatDateTime() function.I recommend the linked documentation for further info.

Comment: @Krilla13 I'm dying to know, did this answer suit your situation?